# How to get a sites nodes in the topnavbar in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a site called MySite
in this site I have a document library called Resources and two subsites called site1 and site2.

On MySite I have a top nav bar with links:
MySite | Resources | Site1 | Site2

When I try to get the navigation nodes I only get one of them and that is Resources (I want to get site1 and site2 so that I can modify them). How can I get all nodes, regardless of if it's a document library or subsite?

Code I use:

```
SPNavigationNodeCollection topNavBar = parentID.Navigation.TopNavigationBar;
string nodes ="";
foreach (SPNavigationNode node in topNavBar)
{
nodes += node.Url.ToString();
}

label1.Text = nodes;
```

Why do I only get the Resources node?

**EDIT**
I can add a proper link to the parent site with

newWeb.ParentWeb.Navigation.TopNavigationBar.AddAsLast(new SPNavigationNode(newSiteName, newSiteName + "/pages/home.aspx"));

this will now get me to the wiki and since subsites inherit navigation the link will be the same on them. However, with this I get two links to the wiki, one that's working with the code above and one that's broken so I try to delete that one in a similar way to how I add the correct one. I would hope that there would be a more convenient way of doing it though.

Comment: What user account is running the code? Does it have permissions to view the sub sites? You could try elevating the context.

Comment: site collection admin. You think I would get not only library nodes but also subsites nodes if I elevated the context? Updated my post a bit

Comment: what site definition is it based on team, publishing or something else?

Comment: parent sites are team sites and to these I add an enterprise wiki (should probably be wiki library yes) and blog site

Comment: I get the nodes now, don't know what I did wrong before but I now try to change the URL with foreach (SPNavigationNode node in newWeb.ParentWeb.Navigation.TopNavigationBar)
{
if(node.Title == newSiteName)
{
node.url = newSiteName + "/pages/home.aspx";
node.Update();
}
} doesn't work though

Comment: IF I remove the line newWeb.ParentWeb.Navigation.TopNavigationBar.AddAsLast(new SPNavigationNode(newSiteName, newSiteName + "/pages/home.aspx")); I only get the resources node. If I keep that line I get all nodes in the foreach loop

Answer (score 1):

I think the *Resources | Site1 | Site2* are the site collections. To get all the site collection using following code:

```
SPSite site = new SPSite("siteURL");
SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
SPSiteCollection coll = web.webs;
```

You get all the site collection *Resources, Site1, Site2*.

Comment: sorry but what do I do with coll?

Comment: now do for loop in coll and get all the sitecollection name and url what u want.